# Confidence interval due to OLS vs. GLS under autocorrelation

Tags: confidence-interval, least-squares, autocorrelation, generalized-least-squares

If our model has autocorrelation, and we continue to use OLS, will the confidence interval be greater or lesser, as compared to the case when we use GLS in this model?